# Is it possible to adjust level of vibration in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

Is there a way to adjust intensity/level of vibration in iPhone using iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to adjust vibration, it either vibrates or it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to adjust vibration. But, there is a way to access volume of iPhone.

MPVolumeView is used for that. One has to import MediaPlayer.framework for that.

[Have a quick look here](http://goo.gl/90mbf).